# how to fetch hierarchy product's propertise data in html table columns using php/mysql?

Tags: php, datatable, hierarchy

this is our (mysql) database structure and data :

Products:

```
id  |  title
1   |  samsung galaxy
2   |  iphone
```

Propertise: (note : parent Propertise has parent_id=0)

```
id  |  title             | parent_id
1   | screen             |    0
2   | screen size        |    1
3   | screen resolution  |    1
```

Products_Propertise:

```
id  |  products_id   |  propertise_id | value
1   |      1         |       1        |  null
2   |      1         |       2        |  5 inch
3   |      1         |       3        |  500 ppi
4   |      2         |       1        |  null
5   |      2         |       2        |  4.2 inch
6   |      2         |       3        |  330 ppi
```

so we need this html output :

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td> Products : </td>
       <td> samsung galaxy  </td>
       <td> iphone  </td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="parent_Propertise">
       <td> screen : </td>
       <td>  null </td>
       <td>  null </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td> screen size : </td>
       <td>  5 inch </td>
       <td>  4.2 inch</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
       <td> screen resolution : </td>
       <td>  500 ppi </td>
       <td>  330 ppi</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i fetched data in to an array() using this mysql query code :

```
 SELECT Products.name, Products_Propertise.value,Propertise.id,Propertise.title,Propertise.parent_id    
    FROM Products_Propertise
    JOIN Propertise ON Products_Propertise.propertise_id=Propertise.id
    JOIN Products ON Products_Propertise.products_id=Products.id
    WHERE  Products_Propertise.products_id=1 OR Products_Propertise.products_id=2
```

and i used this recursive function to show data in html table :

```
<?php
//index elements by id
foreach ($resutls as $item) {
        $item['subs'] = array();
        $indexedItems[$item['id']] = (object) $item;
}
//assign to parent
$topLevel = array();
foreach ($indexedItems as $item) {
    if ($item->parent_id == 0) {
        $topLevel[] = $item;
    } else {
        $indexedItems[$item->parent_id]->subs[] = $item;
    }
}
//recursive function
function renderMenu($items) {
     $render = "";
     $i=0;
     foreach ($items as $item) {
        if(!empty($item->subs))
        {
            $i++;
            $render .= "<tr class='parent_Propertise'><td>".$item->title."</td><td></td></tr>";
        }else{
            $render .= "<tr><td>".$item->title."</td><td>".$item->value."</td></tr>";
        }

        if (!empty($item->subs))
            {
                $render .= renderMenu($item->subs);
            }

     }//end foreach 
    return $render;
}

echo "<table><tr><td>Products :<td>";
foreach ($resutls as $item) {
        echo "<td>".$item['name']."<td>";       
}
echo "</tr>";
echo renderMenu($topLevel);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

but final output is not that we want !! can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're not fetching the data out of the results

```
$resutls = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

`$resutls` is a [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) *object*, not an array. You're doing this

```
foreach ($resutls as $item) {
```

Instead, what you need is a `while` loop

```
while($item = $resutls->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Or procedural

```
while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resutls)) {
```

Comment: ok i know ,but the big problem is on giving data from $resutls to html -- recursive function